# Why is it necessary to divide the priority range according to the batch size in Prioritized Experience Replay?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers, experience-replay

According to DeepMinds's paper [Prioritized Experience Replay](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf) (2016), specifically Appendix B.2.1 "Proportional prioritization" ([p. 13](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf#page=13)), one should equally divide the priority range $[0, p_\text{total}]$ into $k$ ranges, where $k$ is the size of the batch, and sample a random variable within these sub-ranges. This random variable is then used to sample an experience from the sum-tree according to its priority (probability).

Why do we need to do that? Why not simply sampling $k$ random variables in $[0, p_\text{total}]$ and getting $k$ variables from the sum-tree without dividing the priority range into $k$ different ranges? Isn't this the same?

Comment: This question was also asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/362036).